# Accessing member function in YTable from XController

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

This is a general question about CakePHP 3, I have a substantial OOP background, but I'm new to PHP and am stuck using Cake for a project.  I guess this revolves around conventions.

So say I have some model entity, Apple, with a matching ApplesTable class.  In the ApplesTable class, I've implemented a method to find something from the database.  If I was in the ApplesController, my understanding is that I could write: `$this->Apples->method()` and it would be fine.

However, if I want to access that method in say, the OrangesController, just typing the same thing gives me a fatal error saying "Call to a member function method() on boolean."  From what I found researching, it could be something with it not being able to load the model element so the method call written above would just be producing false, creating the error.

Again, I'm newer to PHP and totally new to Cake, so some of the conventions with the framework are still a little hazy.  Hopefully someone can help clear this up -- thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174654/cant-submit-form-using-create/30174892#30174892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`loadModel()`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models), when you need to use a model table/collection that is not the controller’s default one.

```
// ApplesController
loadModel("Oranges");

$this->Oranges->makeJuice();
$orange_sugar = $this->Oranges->sugar;
```

or if your models are [associated](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html),

```
// ApplesController
$this->Apples->Oranges->makeJuice();
$orange_sugar = $this->Apples->Oranges->sugar;
```

Comment: Ahhhh okay, that makes sense, because only the Apples model is loaded into the Controller following the conventions of the Cake framework.  I think doing an association is probably a better option in my case as it makes sense, fundamentally, based on my scenario.   Thanks!